# Java CachedRowSet.UpdateDate(null) always get error

Tags: java, database, derby

I have observed that java cachedrowset.updateDate(null) or cachedrowset.updateNull(DateColumn) does not work. It always gets error. I tried this on an apache derby database version 16.1 on a nullable Date column. Does anybody experience this error? I am using openjdk 17. I think this is a bug.

I tried to use statement.execute(query). The underlying nullable Date column of my apache derby 16.1 database can be set to null if i update it by executing statement.execute(). but not with cachedrowset.updatexxx(). Can anybody please help me.

```
**This is just a part of my code:**

JDBC_DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
private CachedRowSet cached_RowSet;
RowSetFactory myRowSetFactory;

    
**This is my code that creates the CachedRowSet object:**


myRowSetFactory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
cached_RowSet = myRowSetFactory.createCachedRowSet();
cached_RowSet.setTableName("PROJECTS"); // it is necessary to setTableName equal to the table being queried, in order to update the cached rowset
```

//        CachedRowSetImpl crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();  this does not work.

```
cached_RowSet.setUrl(DATABASE_URL);
cached_RowSet.setUsername(USERNAME);
cached_RowSet.setPassword(PASSWORD);
int [] keys = {1};
cached_RowSet.setKeyColumns(keys);
cached_RowSet.setConcurrency(ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE );
cached_RowSet.setCommand(strQuery);  
cached_RowSet.execute();


**This is the code that updates to Null the Nullable Date Column in Apache Derby:**

cached_RowSet.absolute(row + 1);

cached_RowSet.updateDate("NullableDateColumn", null);  --> gets error
cached_RowSet.updateNull("NullableDateColumn");        --> gets error

cached_RowSet.updateRow();
cached_RowSet.acceptChanges();


**This is the error that i get:**

java.sql.SQLDataException: 22005 : [0] DATE, [1] INTEGER
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:84)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:141)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Util.java:225)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Util.java:220)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(EmbedConnection.java:3208)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.newSQLException(ConnectionChild.java:153)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.dataTypeConversion(EmbedPreparedStatement.java:1714)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.setNull(EmbedPreparedStatement.java:345)
at java.sql.rowset/com.sun.rowset.internal.CachedRowSetWriter.updateOriginalRow(CachedRowSetWriter.java:752)
at java.sql.rowset/com.sun.rowset.internal.CachedRowSetWriter.writeData(CachedRowSetWriter.java:366)
at java.sql.rowset/com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.acceptChanges(CachedRowSetImpl.java:898)  ........ xxxxxxxxx



**But, I can use this:**

cached_RowSet.updateNull("NullableDoubleColumn");    --> this is ok!
cached_RowSet.updateNull("NullableVarCharColumn");   --> this is ok!
cached_RowSet.updateNull("NullableIntegerColumn");   --> this is ok!
cached_RowSet.updateDate("NullableDateColumn",java.sql.Date.valueOf("2023-05-18"));  --> this is ok!

I mean the CachedRowSet object can update to Null every other nullable column but not the nullable date column.
I really think this is a bug. Is this a bug?

I am using Apache Derby Database 16.1 and OpenJDK 17.
```

Comment: Where's your code that creates the `CachedRowSet`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @g00se.

        myRowSetFactory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
        cached_RowSet = myRowSetFactory.createCachedRowSet();
        cached_RowSet.setTableName("PROJECTS"); 
     
        cached_RowSet.setUrl(DATABASE_URL);
        cached_RowSet.setUsername(USERNAME);
        cached_RowSet.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        int [] keys = {1};
        cached_RowSet.setKeyColumns(keys);
        cached_RowSet.setConcurrency(ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE );
        cached_RowSet.setCommand(strQuery);  
        cached_RowSet.execute();

Comment: @g00se
This is the code that updates to Null the Nullable Date Column in Apache Derby:

 cached_RowSet.absolute(row + 1);

 cached_RowSet.updateDate("NullableDateColumn", null);  --> gets error
 cached_RowSet.updateNull("NullableDateColumn");        --> gets error

 cached_RowSet.updateRow();
        cached_RowSet.acceptChanges();


 This is the error that i get:

 java.sql.SQLDataException: 22005 : [0] DATE, [1] INTEGER
 at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:84)
 at

Comment: @g00se

But, I can use this:
 
 cached_RowSet.updateNull("NullableDoubleColumn);     --> this is ok!
 cached_RowSet.updateNull("NullableVarCharColumn");   --> this is ok!
 cached_RowSet.updateNull("NullableIntegerColumn");   --> this is ok!
 cached_RowSet.updateDate("NullableDateColumn",java.sql.Date.valueOf("2023-05-18"));  --> this is ok!

 I mean the CachedRowSet object can update to Null every other nullable column but not the nullable date column.
 I really think this is a bug. Is this a bug?

 I am using Apache Derby Database 16.1 and OpenJDK 17.

Comment: The column is *actually* called "NullableDateColumn" ?

Comment: @g00se.
Thanks for your response.
The column is not actually called "NullableDateColumn". I just meant that that column is a Date column that is Nullable.

Comment: OK I think you really need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can test it